# Setup ngnix server in ubuntu server to deploy UI

Tags: ubuntu, nginx

I have installed nginx. and while checkin status its showing below error

```
$ systemctl status ngnix
Unit ngnix.service could not be found.
```

How to Setup ngnix server in ubuntu server to deploy UI

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Probably that's because after initial install, by default the service is masked.

Try:

```
sudo systemctl unmask nginx.service
sudo systemctl enable nginx.service
sudo systemctl start nginx.service
```

**Updated:**

```
sudo rm /etc/systemd/system/multi-user.target.wants/nginx.service
sudo ln -s /usr/lib/systemd/system/nginx.service /etc/systemd/system/multi-user.target.wants/nginx.service
sudo systemctl daemon-reload
sudo systemctl start nginx.service
```

The above commands did the trick.

Comment: I tried unmask..While enabling its showing the same error "Failed to enable unit: Unit file ngnix.service does not exist."

Comment: How did you install Nginx? Compiled from sources or via package manager? And please give an output of:  `ls -la /lib/systemd/system/`

Comment: ls -la /lib/systemd/system giivng so many files..Could you sepecify for which file you want to see the permissions

Comment: You have to be sure that `nginx.service` unit file is in place. There should be a file, `/lib/systemd/system/nginx.service`. If not then you have to add it manually.

Comment: and In that file 'daemon on; master_process on;' is there for ExecStartPre,ExecStart,ExecRelaod..Is that normal?

Comment: Ok then: `sudo ln -s /usr/lib/systemd/system/nginx.service /etc/systemd/system/multi-user.target.wants/nginx.service`  after that:  `sudo systemctl daemon-reload` and then `sudo systemctl start nginx.service`

Comment: ln: failed to create symbolic link '/etc/systemd/system/multi-user.target.wants/nginx.service': File exists

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/215381/discussion-between-stella-and-mgsxman).

Comment: Make sure that you are executing all the commands above with a `sudo`. You have to be an admn with sudo priveleges to do that.